# Issue with state management in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am not able to resolve the below issue, hence seeking help here.

I have the below react component which I am navigating to after creating a entity.. Create -> Overview. In the overview I pass the entityId and then Load it via API and render in the overview page.

```
export default function FlowOverviewComponent() {
  let { flowId = "" } = useParams();

  const [flow, setFlow] = useState<Flow>({
    id: "",
    flowName: "",
    flowDescription: "",
    type: "flow",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadFlow = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8081/flow/".concat(flowId));
      setFlow(response.data);
    }

    loadFlow();
  }, []);
```

Binding below:

```
<TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Flow Name"
              variant="outlined"
              //defaultValue=""
              value={flow.flowName}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFlow({...flow, flowName: e.target.value})
              }
            />

            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Flow Description"
              variant="outlined"
              //defaultValue=""
              value={flow.flowDescription}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFlow({...flow, flowDescription: e.target.value})
              }
            />
```

I am expecting that the flow details are displayed in the controls. But seems like the flow state is being reset.

Comment: And you have confirmed `response.data` is non-null? Are your inputs initially populating with the expected value but things reset on change?

Comment: @qslabs Yes, response.data is not null. Somehow the ```       setFlow(response.data);
``` isnt setting the state. For example if I initialise the state with some other value, that value is populated in the field.

Comment: @Hatana sorry, Dint get you.

Comment: @Nikhil can you drop an example value of `response.data`?

Comment: Rest response ===> ```"{\"id\":\"cf21aa6e-e9ef-4aa7-af0a-286fc2b507d0\",\"flowName\":\"sdf\",\"flowDescription\":\"sdf\",\"type\":\"flow\"}"
```

Comment: ```response.data ==>  {"id":"cf21aa6e-e9ef-4aa7-af0a-286fc2b507d0","flowName":"sdf","flowDescription":"sdf","type":"flow"}
```

Comment: Btw, is it the correct way to initialize an object state? considering its a controlled flow? just seems like an overhead

Comment: This is the correct way to initialize it, yes. You could simplify it slightly by having it initialize to `null` and then conditionally reference properties of `flow` in your JSX but that's about all that could be reduced.

Comment: @Nikhil I threw as much of your code as I could into a StackBlitz and was able to get the JSX to respond to asynchronous changes made in your `useEffect`. So I would advise hitting a breakpoint at your `setFlow` call in `useEffect` simply to confirm `response.data` aligns with the expected structure of `Flow` when invoked.

Comment: @qslabs ok, will try that and get back! Thank you so much for investing time to help!

Answer (score 0):

trying using

```
setFlow((prevFlow) => {
  return { ...prevFlow, flowName: e.target.value };
});
```

Comment: Hi Folks, It worked. What I added is this line .. 

`
const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8081/flow/".concat(flowId));
   **let flow : Flow = JSON.parse(response.data); //ADDED THIS PARSING STEP**
      setFlow(flow); 
`

Thanks for all the help and time !

Answer (score 0):

Finally what worked is the below:

```
const response = await axios.get("localhost:8081/flow/".concat(flowId)); 
let flow : Flow = JSON.parse(response.data); //ADDED THIS PARSING STEP 
setFlow(flow);
```